# Missing html in beautifulsoup scrape

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape a table of data from: https://www.pjm.com/planning/services-requests/interconnection-queues.aspx

I am looking to automate this data pull instead of having to manually download the xls file every day. I looked through their documentation and there is no easy way to automate other than to perform a scrape. Looking at the page source, it looks like this data is stored in an "nggrid" table. Specifically, the data is under .

I created a baseline query in python with beautifulsoup to see what the initial output would be.

Here is my initial code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_link = 'https://www.pjm.com/planning/services-requests/interconnection-queues.aspx'

page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)

page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
```

In the data pull stored in page_content, I am not provided with the same information as the page source. Where I expect  and its various sub-information, I am instead provided the following open and closed tags with no data in between:

```
<pjm-nggrid></pjm-nggrid>
```

Does anyone know how to access the data in an nggrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded asynchronously via Javascript. Probably you will want to change `'api-subscription-key'`, you can see the key in Chrome/Firefox developer tools:

NOTE (This will download whole data ~10MB, you can change `'rowCount'` and `'startRow'` to load only part of data)

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://services.pjm.com/PJMPlanningApi/api//Queue/GetFilteredQueues?'

payload = {'filters': [],
    'rowCount':0,
    'startRow':1
}

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.pjm.com',
    'api-subscription-key': 'E29477D0-70E0-4825-89B0-43F460BF9AB4'
}

json_data = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload).json()

print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "requestType": "GI",
            "queueNumber": "A01",
            "projectName": null,
            "commercialName": "Ironwood",
            "stateProvinceName": "PA",
            "countyName": "Lebanon",
            "projectStatus": "In Service",
            "transmissionOwner": "ME",
            "mw": 720.0,
            "mwe": 720.0,
            "mwc": 673.0,
            "mweInservice": 673.0,

...and so on.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm new to web scraping and working with these tools so this was super helpful. Moving forward, what do you find is the best way to get the correct url for scraping this kind of data? I followed the steps at [link](http://www.gregreda.com/2015/02/15/web-scraping-finding-the-api/) and it seemed to match up with the info you provided.

Comment: @DaveWilson Well, every page is a little bit different in this regards. But opening the Firefox/Chrome developer tools and looking where (and how) the page is making requests is good start.

Answer (score -2):

What about automating xls/xml file download and parsing it instead of **scraping**?